# How do I make my Jekyll Blog have titles with the page number?

Tags: jekyll

Google Webmaster tools complains about pages with the same title. I'm trying to figure out how to make my blog index pages have different titles (by including the page number)

I set my titles through frontmatter so they are available to my base template.

I can't set the title in frontmatter to include the page number, since frontmatter doesn't evaluate variables.

I also tried `{% assign page.title = 'freestyle' %}` but found out [page.title isn't really a variable](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/302)

I created a new variable called titleOverwrite which correctly gets the data I want. Unfortunately it isn't scoped in my base template.

How can I get the titles to include the blog page number?

Here is what I tried:

Base Template

```
{% assign title = page.title %}
{% if page.overwriteTitle %}
  {% assign title = page.overwriteTitle %} 
{% endif %}
<title>{{title}} {{page.subtitle}}</title>
```

blog index.html

```
{% assign overwriteTitle = page.title | append: ' Page ' | append: paginator.page %}
<p>prove it works  </p>
<p> {{ overwriteTitle }} </p>
```

Comment: About downvotes. Sometimes, when people are not able to understand the question, they think this is a bad question. This often comes from to a lack of knowledge, not reading the question twice, or simply basic haters. World is like this, but let's go ahead !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**_includes/head.html or any template affecting title tag**

We test the `paginator` variable which is only present in paginated pages :

```
<title>
{% if paginator %}
  {% assign overwriteTitle = page.title | append: ' Page ' | append: paginator.page %}
  {{ overwriteTitle }}
{% else %}
  {% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}
{% endif %}
</title>
```

Comment: So, maybe, you can approve it.